# Inconsistent results in Spring Data JPA Query vs. Native Query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, oracle10g, spring-data

In an application, I have this query in a Spring Data JPA Repository, pointing to an Oracle 10g database:

```
@Query("select a.AETTELE_CDAT from Aettele a "
  + "where a.AETTELE_CARG = :carg and a.AETTELE_CTAB = :ctab and a.AETTELE_DDATSCA >= :dataValidita and a.AETTELE_DDATVAL <= :dataValidita  and a.AETTELE_CIST = :institute")
public String findByCargAndCtab(@Param("carg") final String carg, @Param("institute") final String institute,
  @Param("ctab") final String ctab, @Param("dataValidita") final String dataValidita);
```

Which, as per hibernate.show-SQL, translates into this query:

```
select aettele0_.AETTELE_CDAT as col_0_0_ from Aettele aettele0_ where aettele0_.AETTELE_CARG=? and aettele0_.AETTELE_CTAB=? and aettele0_.AETTELE_DDATSCA>=? and aettele0_.AETTELE_DDATVAL<=? and aettele0_.AETTELE_CIST=?
```

I stopped execution of the aforementioned application just before the query and manually copy-pasted the parameters (taken from live data in my application) into the query, which then looks like this:

```
select aettele0_.AETTELE_CDAT as col_0_0_ from Aettele aettele0_ where aettele0_.AETTELE_CARG='03268' and aettele0_.AETTELE_CTAB='0001' and aettele0_.AETTELE_DDATSCA>='2016-12-19' and aettele0_.AETTELE_DDATVAL<='2016-12-19' and aettele0_.AETTELE_CIST='*****';
```

I then executed the query on a DB client and stepped over the query on the application.
In the first case, the query returns a result. In the second case, it returns NULL.
The database is obviously the same. I think it is a problem with parameter translation in Spring Data JPA, but can't point what precisely. Does anyone has any idea?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: All the parameters are STRING on the Java side and CHAR on the Oracle side.

Comment: what is the type of `aettele0_.AETTELE_DDATSCA` I mean the data type of the values you will be setting to hibernate query?

Comment: All the parameters are Strings mapping to CHAR, edited the question.

Comment: what about `aettele0_.AETTELE_DDATSCA>='2016-12-19'` this then?

Comment: AETTELE_DDATSCA is a CHAR(10) as well as AETTELE_DDATVAL.

Comment: If data gets change in Aettele this could be due to transaction boundaries. #justGuessing

Comment: spaces that you miss when copying around your values can be another source of such weird effect.

Comment: In order to debug, you could remove parts of the where clause, until you get some results. Might have to change `select a.AETTELE_CDAT` to `select max(a.AETTELE_CDAT)` or similar

Comment: Char(N) is worst datatype to choose. Due to padding with spaces, you never know what you will store in the database. Try to remove predicates one by one till you find which of your assumptions is wrong.

Comment: If there are all chars in the database then how operations like `<=` are supposed to work?

Comment: @M.Deinum they where is the problem? it just uses lexical sorting.

Comment: @ibre5041 I completely agree with you, unluckily I don't have the luxury to choose which legacy data and/or platforms I have to work with.

Comment: Hmm. Does that work for (VAR)CHAR columns as well? Last time I tried it didn't work (but that was quite a couple of years ago :) ).